# AWS CodePipeline Fails on Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

The CodeBuild portion of my pipeline keeps failing with the following error:

```
BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/diag_test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: CodeBuild
```

I did some beginning research and saw that maybe the IAM role it was using didn't have enough permissions so I attached the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess policy to the role and attempted again - same results.

I verified the URI is correct.

What am I missing?

buildspec.yaml below:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 12345678.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=12345678.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/diag_test
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"diag_test","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Thanks in advance for the assist! :)

Comment: You pull image from the same AWS account or a different account? Can you use raw values in buildspec file for testing (not use environment variables)? I think the problem is in codebuild role but ECRfullaccess is enough. This document may help you (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html). Btw, you should define environment variables in **env:** block.

Comment: @FranxiHidro I totally skipped the environment variables for CodeBuild somehow. Thanks for the point in the right direction. Things are failing still but with a different error this time I'll have to open a new question for. Definitely not the easiest AWS service to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 0):

If you pull the ECR image in the CodeBuild pipeline, you should add this line:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ACCOUNT_NUMBER.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

You need to login like you did with Docker login.

If you use custom image for CodeBuild, you should add ECR policy